# Excise just the rotted and molded plywood out from the cabinet. What could go wrong?

Tags: mold, cabinets, dry-rot

We have some water damage / mold / rot in the kitchen sink cabinet in the house we just bought. See the following photos: [EDIT: Inlined the photos per suggestion, though downscaled.]

I've talked to a couple contractors now who suggest they could maybe kinda sorta try to remove the whole cabinet box from the kitchen island, but depending on how well attached the cabinet box is to the rest of the island (neighboring boxes and countertop), this could just turn into a whole kitchen island replacement. Ugh.

I've thought about going in myself with some kind of saw, excise out just the plywood parts that look damaged, mold treat the exposed areas as a precaution, and get a partial box built inside the existing box sufficient to complement what would be left of the existing box.

How bad of an idea is this? What could go wrong?

And if I go forward with trying to excise out just the damaged parts, what kind of saw should I use? I have one of these oscillating multi-tools, [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07QV6ZYVJ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QV6ZYVJ), and the video in that Amazon link does suggest that it can indeed cut through plywood...

(FYI, copying post from r/HomeImprovement that I guess isn't getting any traction because I have no karma...)

EDIT: Adding photos inline, though I'm having to downscale the resolution:
[image: whole island]
[image: whole cabinet]
[image: cabinet closeup]
[image: cabinet closeup - left]
[image: cabinet closeup - center]
[image: cabinet closeup - right]
[image: under veneer]

Comment: Is the wood rotten(soft/push your finger though) or just moldy?  If rotten can probably cut out rotten section/s and using 2x2s support new pieces.  If wood just moldy and solid, just kill the mold.  Bleach is good among others.

Comment: doesn't look bad.  you'll get better traction if you add the pictures to the post instead of link.  i replaced the bottom of a similar cabinet where the bottom piece turned to compost in my hand.  used an osc tool to remove it then just added some pt 2x4 sleepers and cut a new piece of plywood to fit.  first thing you should do is cleanup your disposal piping and make sure there is no more slow leak.

Comment: I tripped over a document on mold the other day that was an interesting counterpoint to mold fears: https://www.wwpa.org/resources/mold-and-wood-products. The dummies put it behind a registration process, so it's annoyingly difficult to look at. The org has a monetary interest in defending wood's viability as a building material. For all I know, the two authors are the org's favorite expert witnesses for defending against mold lawsuits.

Comment: Usually kitchen cabinet boxes are screwed together. You should be able to find the screws (maybe hidden behind door hinges, or counter sunk and filled with putty - use a magnet to find 'em), then just unscrew the one damaged box and replace it.

Comment: "Is the wood rotten(soft/push your finger though) or just moldy?" The "damaged" area is definitely softer / gives more than the "normal" looking plywood, so it looks like at a minimum it needs to be cut out.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing structural there (judging from the first two images). Remove the loose bits of wood, use a wood hardener on any remaining spongey bits, and use an epoxy based wood filler to flatten things out again. For appearance, maybe paint the back or apply a 1/8" layer of plywood as a veneer.

Comment: Both the bottom of the back panel and back of the bottom panel give when I'm just pressing against it with my finger, so it seems that area of the box has lost a substantial amount of its innate support / stiffness. Your suggestion doesn't sound unreasonable (I wasn't even aware that wood hardener was a thing!), but should I be at all concerned with the mold permeating the plywood, and/or growing on the underside/backside of the box?

Comment: @rarely, just be sure to eliminate the moisture source(s). If you or somebody there is sensitive to mold, then I would get a mold killer from the hardware store (bleach is pretty impotent for wood, although I guess 8% or so vinegar works on some molds). I'd find something marketed for mold and make sure that bleach or vinegar alone isn't the active ingredient. No sensitivities? I would bury it without a second thought. For the wood hardener get a cheap paint brush (with bristles, not foam) that fits down in the can. That stuff can be difficult to apply without getting it all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for the info!